# Toggle button with add and remove css

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to make toggle button with add and remove or replace css,
this my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#wrapper").click( function() {
    if ($('.toggle').css({top: '-1000px'})) {
      $('.toggle').css({top: '0px'});
    } else {
      $('.toggle').css({top: '-1000px'})
    }
    // my toggle button is animate hamburger to 'x' button
    $(".icon").toggleClass("close");
  });

})
```

Comment: this case to show and hide navbar with toggle button

Comment: Adding/removing inline CSS is a pain. Just use `toggleClass()` as you do for the `.icon` element

Comment: I try to the same rule but didn't work,

Comment: I can guarantee you that it does. If it's not working for you then we need to see a more complete example of your code so we can help you debug it

Comment: Voting to close the question since _It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement is setting the `$('.toggle')` position, not getting it. You would want something like this:

```
if ($('.toggle').css('top') === '-1000px') { }
```

But you could simplify this even further with a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and some jQuery [chaining](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp):

```
$("#wrapper").on('click', function() {
  $('.toggle').css('top', $('.icon').toggleClass('close').hasClass('close') ? '-1000px' : '0px');
});
```